# Determine convergence or divergence $\sum \frac {1-e^{-n} \log n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine convergence or divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1-e^{-n} \log n}{n}$$

If $n$ is large => $e^{-n} \rightarrow 0 => e^{-n} \log n \rightarrow 0 $

It follows that when n is large $\frac {1-e^{-n} \log n}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$

But comparison test is inconclusive as $\sum \frac{1}{n} = \infty$

I tried other tests, but I think I am not manipulating them correctly

How would you one like this? Much appreciated for the help.

Comment: Use `$\implies$` for $\implies$

Comment: It is true that $e^{-n}\log n \to 0$ but the reasoning $e^{-n} \to 0 \implies e^{-n}\log n \to 0$ is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right way. Since $e^{-n}\log n\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $e^{-n}\log n<\frac12$ and therefore
$$
\frac{1-e^{-n}\log n}{n}>\frac1{2n}.
$$
This implies
$$
\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1-e^{-n}\log n}n\geq \frac12\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1n=\infty.
$$
Your series is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

Use *equivalents*:

Rewrite the general of this series as $$\dfrac{\mathrm e^n-\log n}{n\mkern 1.5mu\mathrm e^n}\sim_\infty\dfrac{\mathrm e^n}{n\mkern 1.5mu\mathrm e^n}=\dfrac 1n,\quad\text{which diverges.}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** From
$$\sum \frac {1-e^{-n} \log n}{n}=\sum \frac {1}{n}-\sum \frac {\log n}{ne^n}$$
shows **diverge-Converge=diverge**.